# Restart IIS application pool in post-build action using powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, iis, post-build-event

I want to restart IIS application pool in c# project post-build action. I have this powershell script RestartPool.ps1:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$pool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\MyPool
$pool.Recycle()
```

It works fine from console but in post-build action:

```
Powershell -File "$(SolutionDir)RestartPool.ps1"
```

throws error "Unable to invoke method for null expression" for line with $pool.Recycle().
What's wrong?

Comment: `$pool = Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\MyPool` this is the part that is actually failing. permissions issue?

Comment: @Matt Visual studio is run as administrator.